# Find all the substrings in string with regex javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I have a rich text editor and it produces output which includes hyperlinks as well. For example `<p><a href="test.com" target="_blank">Link1</a>&nbsp;fsdfsdf <a href="google.com" target="_blank">Link2</a>&nbsp;fsdffsdfs</p>`
 I need to get all the `<a>`tags and `href`s in them so that I can run a validation for example if it's an external link, so that i can add `nofollow`tag etc. What kind of regex should I be using? Or anything other than regex maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends. Are you editing an HTML text file? Or are you using a JS script on a web page to select certain DOM elements?

Comment: @jkdev Kind of an HTML text file, no DOM elements are included. I'm using a CMS product and I have text areas for users to enter context.

Answer (score 1):

> need to get all the tags and hrefs in them
>
> Or anything other than regex maybe?

Try creating an element to set editor text as `.innerHTML` , use `.map()` to return array of `a` element `href` attribute values

```
// editor text
var html = document.querySelector("#editor").textContent,
    // element to store `html` from editor
    div = document.createElement("div"),
    // set `div` `.innerHTML` to editor text
    div.innerHTML = html;
// `links` : all `a` elements ; `list` : `links` `href` values
var links = [].slice.call(div.querySelectorAll("a")),
    list = links.map(function(el) {
      return el.href
    });
// filter `list`, set `rel="nofollow"` attribute at `a` element
// within `links` where condition at `if` returns `true`
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   if (/* condition ; for example if it's an external link */) {
     links[i].setAttribute("rel", "nofollow")
   }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a text editor, so you'll need to parse that text into the DOM, first.